# How this formula of posterior probability is derived?

Tags: math, statistics, data-science, linear-algebra, probability

I was going through the book "Elements of Statistical Learning", reading chapter 4 - Linear Methods for Classification... and got stuck on this equation... It is written that this is a popular model for posterior probabilities. But I searched everywhere and not got the exact proof of this equation I want to know how this formula is derived.

[this is the image of the formula taken from the book..pg
102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ra2f.jpg)

formula

**Pr(G = 1|X = x) =exp(β0 + βT x) / 1 + exp(β0 + βT x)**

**Pr(G = 2|X = x) = 1 / 1 + exp(β0 + βT x)**

I know the basic formula of posterior probability, i.e., p(x | y) = p(y | x)p(x) /p(y) but this formula is new to me. How we can relate expectation to the posterior probability formula?

Please stick to the basics while answering this question as I am a beginner.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the formula for logistic regression. In logistic regression, the outcome y is binary given success probability pi. That is, y|pi ~ Bernoulli(pi). In GLM, a parameter (usually the mean) is always connected to the data via a link function; for logistic regression it is the logit function. The model is: y|pi ~ Bernoulli(pi); logit(pi) = XB. The definition of logit is logit(pi) = pi/(1+pi) = XB. Solving for pi gives pi = e^XB/(1+e^XB). Since pi is the parameter of the Bernoulli, it is by definition P(y = 1 | X = x) = pi = e^XB/(1+e^XB). For your formula, B0 + BTX is the same as XB, written with the intercept (B0) plus the parameters (B) transposed against X. Of course, 1 - pi = 1/(1+e^XB) (try it out yourself) which is the probability of a failure (defined as 2 in this case), P(y = 2 | X = x) = 1/1+e^XB.

Comment: can you suggest me any other book or source that can help me clear my basics related to these topics so that I can read this book "ESL"..? Like i knew about logit function but never read about this derivation of relations???...

Comment: https://www.springboard.com/blog/data-science/what-is-logistic-regression/ If you need clarification feel free to ask